# Use custom secret inside values on helm

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm trying to deploy Airflow using the official helm chart. I want to pass the user and password of the web server using a Kubernetes secret.

I've created the secrets using:

```
kubectl create secret generic webserverpw --from-literal=password=123456
kubectl create secret generic webserverus --from-literal=user=test
```

Then I changed the secret section on the `values.yaml` from the official helm to:

```yaml
# Secrets for all airflow containers
secret:
# - envName: ""
#   secretName: ""
#   secretKey: ""
  - envName: "WS_USER"
    secretName: "webserverus"
    secretKey: "user"
  - envName: "WS_PW"
    secretName: "webserverpw"
    secretKey: "password"
```

Then, I referenced the envs on the `defaultUser` section of the `values.yaml`

```yaml
defaultUser:
    enabled: true
    role: Admin
    username: $(WS_USER)
    email: admin@example.com
    firstName: User
    lastName: Test
    password: $(WS_PW)
```

Although, when I try to deploy the Helm using ArgoCD the pod `create-user` throws an error:

```
  Warning  BackOff    35s (x7 over 2m28s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

When I use `k describe pod create-user` I noticed that the env variables are not passed to the script (the script is in `values.yaml`):

```
bash
      -c
      exec \
      airflow users create "$@"
      --
      -r
      Admin
      -u
      $(WS_USER)
      -e
      admin@example.com
      -f
      User
      -l
      Test
      -p
      $(WS_PW)
```

So, my doubt is: How can I use the custom secret variable inside values.yml?

Comment: env vars should be referenced as `${}` or just `$` - i believe surrounding with parenthesis wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I do not believe can do what you show in the `defaultUser` key by passing `$(WS_USER)`. Based on your values alone, I have to assume you are mounting those secrets as ENV variables in the pod. By passing in `$()` type values to `values.yaml` they are merely interpreted as strings. In your pod entrypoint script, rather than referencing `$username` just use `$WS_USER`. This assumes you're mounting those secrets to the pod as your values.yaml might suggest.